# ShinobiCharts on ColllectionView crashes with loadDataInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, shinobi

I have ShinobiChart added in a CollectionViewCell. Initially I had a delay while displaying the charts.

Using `loadDataInBackground` reduced delay significantly. However when I scroll repeadly and fast on CollectionView the App crashes.

Any idea for the solution. It does not crash when `loadDataInBackground` is disabled.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5cYPK.png